# C++11 auto return type in template methods

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, auto

I would like to write a general function to search in different containers.
Cointainers contain shared pointers to different types. At the moment I have this

```
    template<typename TInstance, typename THandle, typename TContainer>
    auto FindInContainer(TContainer& container, THandle handle) -> decltype(boost::shared_ptr<TInstance>())
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);

        const auto& found = std::find_if(container.begin(), container.end(), 
            [handle](typename TContainer::value_type& instance)
            {
                return instance.get() == reinterpret_cast<typename TContainer::value_type::element_type*>(handle.handle);
            });

        if (found == container.end())
            return boost::shared_ptr<TInstance>();

        return *found;
    }
```

I use MSVC 2015 Update 1, but somehow it cannot figure out the TInstance type, even though I used the return type specified (whatever the term for the thing for the -> operator in the method signature).

```
return FindInContainer<SensorController>(_sensors, handle); // Works
return FindInContainer(_sensors, handle); // Does not compile
```

The _sensors is defined as

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<SensorController>> _sensors;
```

Is my C++ is rusty, or the compiler does not support this type deduction?

Comment: You need to stop using `TInstance`, and instead use `typename TContainer::value_type`; there is no way for the compiler to deduce the value of the `TInstance` template parameter from the return type.

Comment: @Mankarse - You are right. I thought because of the last line "return *found", it may find out the type of TInstance, but looks it was not able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template argument cannot be deduced from the *return type* of a function template. Only *parameters* of the function template participate in template argument deduction. Since `TInstance` does not figure in any of the parameters of `FindInContainer`, it cannot be deduced.

If VS 2015 Update 1 supports it, you could use return type deduction (a C++14 feature) for the function template (omit the return type altogether):

```
template<typename THandle, typename TContainer>
auto FindInContainer(TContainer& container, THandle handle)
{
  // ... as before
}
```

If that's not supported, you can resort to extracting the type from the container (as you're already doing):

```
template<typename THandle, typename TContainer>
typename TContainer::value_type FindInContainer(/*...*/)
{
  // ... as before
}
```

Comment: You still have the non-deducible `TInstance` template parameter in there.

Comment: Thanks, both ways work: with explicit type and with auto, too. So the takeaway is: "A template argument cannot be deduced from the return type of a function template."